# React Native - How can I display pdf file in webview

Tags: webview, react-native-ios

I have downloaded pdf file url and fetch from document directory path in iOS. But its not working. I m getting proper file path from document directory.

Code:

```
 <WebView source={{ uri: filepath }} onLoad={this.onFinish} style={{ flex:1}} javaScriptEnabled />
```

Answer (score 5):

> ```
> Add this line  originWhitelist={['*']}
>
> <WebView 
>       source={{ uri: filePath }}
>       onLoad={this.onFinish}
>       style={styles.webViewStyles}
>       originWhitelist={['*']} />
> ```
>
> this will work for only ios